# Setting Twig up correctly

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

I have downloaded the tarball from Github including Twig's source, but it's quite unclear to me which parts of the archive to include in my project - there is nothing written about that part.

Sorry that this question is so short, but this is really something I couldn't find in their documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to place lib/Twig somewhere in your project, and in your bootstrap or index file include Twig's autoloader like:

```
require_once '/path/to/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
```

After that you should be able to use it:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('Hello {{ name }}!', array('name' => 'World'));
```